# Stock data linear regression by sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression, normalization, mse

I am using the Sklearn to do the linear regression for a set of stock price data, after I normalized the data, the MSE all becomes 0.
Why I get all MSE 0? and please help me, somebody said it's because the model problem.. but I am python newbie, and really need help, thanks in advance!

here is one row example in the dataset:

```
tdate ,     stock_id ,   open ,  close ,  high ,  low ,   volume

04/01/2000   ,   1  ,    100  ,   98  ,    101  ,  98  ,   283100
```

The code:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn import cross_validation
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import Normalizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

stock1= file[['open','close','high','low','volume']].where(file['stock_id'] 
== 1)
X_stock1 = stock1.drop(['close'],axis=1)
y_stock1 = stock1['close']
X_stock1_train, X_stock1_test, y_stock1_train, y_stock1_test = 
train_test_split(X_stock1, y_stock1, train_size=0.8, random_state=42)
```

### fill in missing value with median

```
X_stock1_train= Imputer(missing_values='NaN', strategy='median', 
axis=0).fit_transform (X_stock1_train)
y_stock1_train=y_stock1_train.reshape(-1,1) 
y_stock1_train=Imputer(missing_values='NaN', strategy='median', axis=0 
).fit_transform (y_stock1_train)
```

## normalized the stock data

```
transformer=Normalizer().fit(X_stock1_train, y_stock1_train)
X_stock1_train=transformer.transform(X_stock1_train)
y_stock1_train=transformer.transform(y_stock1_train)

LinearRegression=LinearRegression()
scores = cross_validation.cross_val_score(LinearRegression, X_stock1_train,
                                          y_stock1_train, scoring= 'neg_mean_ 
                                          squared_error' , cv=10)
```

result:

```
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]

Average accuracy for Linear Regression: 0.0
```

Comment: What are the mean and variance of your data?

Comment: hi, cause there are several attributes, I just put the data here, Stock-all-test1.csv. https://github.com/linruonanjohn/Stock-data